# VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame ERROR -12916 (kVTFormatDescriptionChangeNotSupportedErr)

Tags: ios, objective-c, h.264

I got a problem I can't get my head around.

First I create a `VTCompressionSessionCreate` (h264) then in my compression callback when I start feeding images I get a `CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer` as expected.

Just for debugging the code stream I then create a `VTDecompressionSessionCreate` and feed the 'sampleBuffer' containing the H264 stream to a `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame` and I would expect a `CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer` in my decompression callback.

Now to the problem:

If I create `VTDecompressionSessionCreate` using the 'sampleBuffer' from the compression callback like this:

```
CMFormatDescriptionRef format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
```

Everything works as expected and I get `CVImageBufferRef's` in my decompression callback.

However my intention is to send the data over a network so I need to get my format discription from the in stream SPS and PPS information.

So then I must 'fake' getting the SPS and PPS by first extracting them and then using them like this:

```
CMFormatDescriptionRef format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
size_t spsSize, ppsSize;
size_t parmCount;
const uint8_t* sps, *pps;

CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetH264ParameterSetAtIndex(format, 0, &sps, &spsSize, &parmCount, NULL );
CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetH264ParameterSetAtIndex(format, 1, &pps, &ppsSize, &parmCount, NULL );
const uint8_t* const parameterSetPointers[2] = {sps, pps};
const size_t parameterSetSizes[2] = {spsSize, ppsSize};
CMFormatDescriptionRef format2;
status = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets(kCFAllocatorDefault, 2, parameterSetPointers, parameterSetSizes, 4, &format2);
```

I would expect format and format2 to contain the same information but:

```
format = <CMVideoFormatDescription 0x17004fd50 [0x19483ac80]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'avc1' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: 'avc1'       dimensions: 1280 x 720 
    } 
    extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x170270cc0 [0x19483ac80]>{type = immutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x194935fa0 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "SampleDescriptionExtensionAtoms"} = <CFBasicHash 0x170270c40 [0x19483ac80]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x194939fa0 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "avcC"} = <CFData 0x1700c9920 [0x19483ac80]>{length = 35, capacity = 35, bytes = 0x0164001fffe100106764001fac56c050 ... 28ee3cb0fdf8f800}
}

    2 : <CFString 0x194936000 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "FormatName"} = <CFString 0x17003a160 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "H.264"}
}
}
}
```

format2:

```
format2 = <CMVideoFormatDescription 0x174051c70 [0x19483ac80]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'avc1' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: 'avc1'       dimensions: 1280 x 720 
    } 
    extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x17426f9c0 [0x19483ac80]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x19499a608 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationBottomField"} = <CFString 0x19499a648 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "Center"}
    1 : <CFString 0x19499a328 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x19483ac80]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x194935fa0 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "SampleDescriptionExtensionAtoms"} = <CFBasicHash 0x17426b100 [0x19483ac80]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x174031560 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "avcC"} = <CFData 0x1740c4910 [0x19483ac80]>{length = 35, capacity = 35, bytes = 0x0164001fffe100106764001fac56c050 ... 28ee3cb0fdf8f800}
}

    5 : <CFString 0x19499a5e8 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = <CFString 0x19499a648 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "Center"}
    6 : <CFString 0x1949360e0 [0x19483ac80]>{contents = "FullRangeVideo"} = <CFBoolean 0x19483b030 [0x19483ac80]>{value = false}
}
}
}
```

format works
forma2 don't and `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame` throws error -12916.

Thank you for helping.

.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. It was the way I created `CMFormatDescriptionRef` containing the code stream that was causing the error.

The SPS and PPS was taken from a CFSampleBuffer. Then I create a CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets so far so good. But in the same application I turned around the stream and decoded the picture using the same CFSampleBuffer. That's not working and was causing the error. I had to convert the payload to NSData first then create a new CFSampleBuffer from the NSData. Then it works

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'containing the code stream' means?

Comment: Yes I can see my answer is a bit confusing. Anyhow let me clarify, the SPS and PPS was taken from a CFSampleBuffer. Then I create a CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets so far so good.

But in the same application I turned around the stream and decoded the picture using the same CFSampleBuffer. That's not working and was causing the error. I had to convert the payload to NSData first then create a new CFSampleBuffer from the NSData.. Then it works... good luck with your project.

Comment: @Anders, I've been trying for a while to get this working in iOS.  I read the SPS and PPS manually from NAL buffers received over a network.  I'm sure they're intact because I can use an H.264 soft codec to decode them successfully.  I parse the PPS and SPS and can create the CMVideoFormatDescription, but when I try to u use VTDecompressionSessionCreate, it always fails returning -5.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662387/vtdecompressionsessioncreate-returns-5

Comment: When you create the (VTDecompressionSessionCreate). Then you can: VTDecompressionSessionCanAcceptFormatDescription.  What is the answer then?